# Import html using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'd like to import html code of a website to a file using Excel VBA. How to realize this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's quite a few tutorials for "Scraping html with vba". A good one here: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm using the internet.explorer object and the HTML Object library. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim response As String
Dim httpReq As Object

Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.httpRequest.5.1")

httpReq.Open "GET", "http://google.com", False
httpReq.Send

response = httpReq.responseText
```